# Windows registry key listener is not registering subkeys removed from HKEY_USERS

Tags: windows, go, winapi, registry

I'm using Go's `windows` package, specifically the `windows.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` function:

```
for {
    err := windows.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(
            windows.Handle(key),
            false,
            windows.REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET|windows.REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME,
            windows.Handle(0),
            false,
        )

    // do stuff once event triggers

    ...

}
```

However, I'm not getting any events when a subkey is removed from `HKEY_USERS`. If I monitor some other key, I get an event when a subkey is added or removed. But when I monitor `HKEY_USERS`, I only get an event when a key is added.

What makes `HKEY_USERS` so special in this case?

**EDIT**: It seem like this is because subkeys of `HKEY_USERS` are added/removed via `RegLoadKey()` and `RegUnLoadKey()`. So my question becomes: how do you listen for events from `RegUnLoadKey()`? And why does adding keys via `RegLoadKey()` trigger an event, but removing keys via `RegUnLoadKey` does not?

Answer (score 2):

Using `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` [document example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regnotifychangekeyvalue#examples) with **HKU .DEFAULT** command parameters, I cannot reproduce the behavior. Both Key and Value which are added or deleted under **.DEFAULT** will signal the event.

Comment: [RegLoadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeya) && [RegUnLoadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regunloadkeya) also trigger the event using [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310457/any-example-to-use-regloadkey).